# Mouse position on canvas painting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

The code below paints correctly but it paints to wrong coordinates. It should paint the place where the mouse is. I was not able to discover my mistake. Thanks.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6jqW9/)

```
container.mousedown(function(e) {

    var parentOffset = $(this).offset(); 
    var x = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    var y = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;

    context_temp.beginPath();
    context_temp.moveTo(x, y);
    started = true;
});

container.mousemove(function(e) {

    var parentOffset = $(this).offset(); 
    var x = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    var y = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;

    if (started) {
        context_temp.lineTo(x, y);
        context_temp.stroke();
    }
});

container.mouseup(function(e) {

    var parentOffset = $(this).offset(); 
    var x = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    var y = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;

    if (started) {
        container.mousemove(x, y);
        started = false;
        update();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting your canvas width and height in CSS. That just stretches the canvas the same as it would an image.

The effect is drawing in the wrong place.

Instead you need to set your canvas dimensions on the tag itself:

```
<canvas width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasted my hours for nothing :D. But why it has to be that way?

Comment: Just think of canvas as an <img> element that you can draw into, then it makes more sense.

Comment: Note that you could also set the width / height with JavaScript, like so: canvas.width = '400'; canvas.height = '300';

Comment: @ryanbrill: Yep.  But the height and width properties are numbers, so it'd be better without the quotes. (It'll work either way, but just looks cleaner.)

Comment: @ryanbrill in the corrected fiddle, I did that for his 'temp_canvas' :)

Answer (score 3):

A `<canvas>` has its own `width` and `height`, which not only define its physical size (unless CSS steps in), but also its logical size (the number of rows/columns of pixels on its drawing surface).  When CSS changes the size, the canvas stretches to fit, but doesn't change its *logical* size.  Basically, the pixels stretch too, so the logical and physical coordinates no longer match up.

To fix the problem, you could either do the math to match the coordinates back up, or exclusively use the canvases' own width/height to size them, or set the canvases' width and height properties after the fact to match the width and height set by CSS.